# Why Multer resulting errno -4058 in on nodeJS

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to upload an image along with its data. I am using multer to upload the image. But I keep getting error message like this:

```
{ 
  [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\works\fiverr-kiddiemmerce-be\assets\products\2019-09-13T16:18:26.393Z180911-Naver-x-Dispatch-Yeoreum-cosmic-girls-wjsn-41821990-2000-1333.jpg']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   'D:\\works\\fiverr-kiddiemmerce-be\\assets\\products\\2019-09-13T16:18:26.393Z180911-Naver-x-Dispatch-Yeoreum-cosmic-girls-wjsn-41821990-2000-1333.jpg',
  storageErrors: [] 
}
```

How can I fix this? I have no clue at all. This is what i have done so far.

multer.js

```
const fs           = require('fs');
const multer       = require(`multer`);
const path         = require(`path`);
const productPath  = path.join(__dirname, `../../assets/products`);

const storage      = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.fieldname.includes(`material_image`)) {
            cb(null, materialPath);
        } else if (file.fieldname.includes(`product_image`)) {
            if (!fs.existsSync(productPath)) {
                fs.mkdir(productPath, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
            cb(null, productPath);
        }
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    },
});
const filter    =  (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === `image/png` || file.mimetype === `image/jpeg`) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    upload: multer({
        storage         : storage,
        limits          : { fileSize: 720 * 1280 * 5 },
        fileFilter  : filter,
    }),
};
```

and this is the productController.js (where I want to upload the image)

```
const { upload }      = require(`../utils/multer`);
const multer          = require(`multer`);

module.exports = {
   store: async (req, res) => {
        const img_upload = upload.any();
        img_upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                res.end();
                return;
            } else if (err) {
                console.log(`It always goes here`);
                console.log(err);
                res.end();
                return;
            }
            // Do something if no error
        });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows you can't create files with colon `:`  , so you have to replace colon with dash `new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g , "-")` or change it to timestamp by adding `Date.now()` instead of  `new Date().toISOString()`